# Javascript regex lazy quantifier not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

1) drug A; 2) drug B; **3) drug C - ex**; 4) drug D

How can only the drug that contains the "- ex" string be selected using a regular expression?

```
;.*?- ex
```

gives the following (greedy) result:

1) drug A **; 2) drug B; 3) drug C - ex**; 4) drug D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start the match by matching one or more  digits `\d+` followed by `)` and use a negated character class `[^;]` matching any char except a `;`

The word boundaries `\b` prevent the word characters being part of a larger word.

```
\b\d+\)[^;]*- ex\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ed1gDE/1)